# Set ID of owning side

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have got three `classes`: `Theatre`, `Room`, `Address` which are also tables in db. They are connected like this:

- `One` `Address` to `Many` `Theatre` (it can be shopping mall with many theathres all something like this),
- `One` `Theatre` to `Many` `Room`,

Entities:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "theatres")
public class TheatreEntity extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private AddressEntity address;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "theatre", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<RoomEntity> rooms = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * @return Theatre object mapped from TheatreEntity
     */
    public Theatre toTheatre() {
        return Theatre
                .builder()
                //code
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * @param theatre we want to map
     * @return home entity obejct mapped from home
     */
    public static TheatreEntity fromTheatreToEntity(Theatre theatre) {
     
        return TheatreEntity
                .builder()
                //code
                .build();
    }
}
```

---

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "rooms")
public class Room extends BaseEntity {
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "theatre_rows")
    private Integer rows;
    private Integer places;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "theatre")
    private TheatreEntity theatre;

    /**
     * @return Room object mapped from RoomEntity
     */
    public Room toRoom() {
        return Room
                .builder()
                //code
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * @param room we want to map
     * @return room entity object
     */
    public static RoomEntity fromRooomtoEntity(Room Room) {

        return RoomEntity
                .builder()
                //code
                .build();
    }
}
```

---

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@Entity
@Table(name = "addresses")
public class AddressEntity extends BaseEntity {
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private Integer number;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "address", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<TheatreEntity> theatres = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     *
     * @return Address object mapped from AddressEntity
     */
    public Address toAddress() {
        return Address
                .builder()
                //code
                .build();
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param address we want to map
     * @return address entity object
     */
    public static AddressEntity fromAddressToEntity(Address address) {
      
        return AddressEntity
                .builder()
                //code
                .build();
    }
}
```

Mapping methods:

```
public static TheatreEntity fromTheatreToEntity(Theatre theatre) {
        //apply methods are from TheatreUtils interface when I use this:
        //Function<Theatre, Long> theatreToId = theatre -> theatre.id;
      
        var theatreId = theatreToId.apply(theatre);
        var theatreName = theatreToName.apply(theatre);
        var theatreAddress = theatreToAddress.apply(theatre);
        var theatreRooms = theatreToCinemaRooms.apply(theatre);

        return TheatreEntity
                .builder()
                .id(theatreId)
                .name(theatreName)
                .address(fromAddressToEntity(theatreAddress))
                .theatreRooms(theatreRooms
                        .stream()
                        .map(RoomEntity::fromRooomtoEntity)
                        .toList())
                .build();
    }
    
 public static RoomEntity fromRooomtoEntity(Room room) {
        var roomId = toTheatreRoomId.apply(room);
        var roomName = toTheatreRoomName.apply(room);
        var roomRows = toTheatreRoomRows.apply(room);
        var roomTheatre = toTheatreRoomTheatre.apply(room);
        var roomPlaces = toTheatreRoomPlaces.apply(room);
        
        return RoomEntity
                .builder()
                .id(roomId)
                .name(roomName)
                .rows(roomRows)
                .cinema(fromTheatreToEntity(roomTheatre))
                .places(roomPlaces)
                .build();
    }
```

And my `DTOs` classes

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@ToString
public class CreateTheatreDto {
    private String name;
    private CreateAddressDto address;
    private List<CreateRoomDto> rooms;

    public Theatre toTheatre() {
        return Theatre
                .builder()
                .name(name).address(address).rooms(rooms)
                .build();
    }
}

--------------------------

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class CreateRoomDto {
    private String name;
    private Integer rows;
    private Integer places;
 
    public Room toRoom() {
        return Room
                .builder()
                .name(name).rows(rows).places(places)
                .build();
    }
}

--------------------------


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class CreateAddressDto {
    private String city;
    private String street;
    private Integer number;

    public Address toAddress() {
        return Address
                .builder()
                .city(city).street(street).number(number)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And the `method` which I use to add the `Theatre` object to `database`

```
    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
    public CreateTheatreDto createTheatre(CreateTheatreDto createTheatreDto) {
        var theatre = createTheatreDto.toTheatre();
     
        var rooms = createTheatreDto
                .getRooms()
                .stream()
                .map(CreateRoomDto::toRoom)
                .peek(room -> room.setTheatre(theatre))
                .toList();

        theatre.setRooms(rooms);

        return theatreRepository
                .add(theatre)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new TheatreServiceException("Cannot insert theatre"));
    }
```

The `.add` method from `theatreRepository`

```
public Optional<Theatre> add(Theatre theatre) {
        var theatreEntity = fromTheatreToEntity(theatre);
        var insertedTheatre = theatreEntityDao.save(theatreEntity);

        return Optional.ofNullable(insertedTheatre.toTheatre());
    }
```

The `body` I use to add `Theatre` to `db`

```
{
    "name":"Name",
    "address": {
        "city":"City",
        "street":"Street",
        "number": 12
    },
    "rooms": [
        {
            "name":"Room",
            "rows": 10,
            "places":8
        },
        {
            "name":"RoomRoom",
            "rows": 8,
            "places":8
        }
    ]
}
```

Then, when I want to add the object by post method, the `Theatre` with `Address` is added correctly - `theatre` in database has `address_id`, but the `room` has `theatre_id` column fill with null

I really do not know what is wrong with my code. I think that I set the id of both sides correct, but its not.

Comment: I can't see any problem with the mapping between theatre and room but did you check that when you call ` theatreRepository.add(theatre)` the references are set correctly? Also, could you share your repository, i.e. what does `add(Theatre)` look like?

Comment: Ive just added `add(Theatre)` method to the post

Comment: It is also strange that when I want to `print` `theatre` and `rooms` in `createTheatre` method to see if I objects are mapped correctly, and I use `System.out.println(theatre)` after this line: `theatre.setRooms(rooms)` I got `StackOverflow: null` error

Comment: You should post the content of that method then and maybe the stackoverflow error with its stacktrace. It also seems you have more than 2 "layers" here: DTO -> Theatre -> Entity. Why? I'd say DTO -> Entity should be enough and maybe the step Theatre -> Entity is what causes the problem. Also `return Optional.ofNullable(insertedTheatre.toTheatre());` is somewhat superfluous: if `insertedTheatre` is `null` you'd get a NPE anyway and if it isn't then I'd expect `toTheatre()` not to return `null`.

Comment: peek() does allow to change things as part of the stream, but it is recommended not to do that.
StackOverflow is related to infinite loop most likely - when printing theathre you print entire room, and when printing room you print entire theatre probably.
Also, createTheatre while important is not the main thing you should be concerned about - are all the fields set correctly after `fromTheatreToEntity`?

Comment: My best guess actually would be that in `fromTheatreToEntity` you set Rooms list in Theatre, but don't have back reference in Room - and Room is the owning entity of the relationship

Comment: @Deltharis exactly my guess as well :)

Comment: added my mapping methods to post, I get this error: `java.lang.StackOverflowError: null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire apply business in mappers looks kind of weird and I'm not sure what you gain out of it, but I'm going to assume they work as advertised.

What you're missing is a back-reference in Room(Entity) to TheatreEntity. In mapping you build TheatreEntity, set list of Rooms it holds as just mapped Rooms - that means that in Room(Entity) you don't have a reference to the new TheatreEntity. And Room is the entity that owns the relationship, that's the table where the connection would be saved. Hence your trouble.

In order to avoid StackOverflowError while printing you have to adjust your toString methods - Room should probably not print entire Theatre object (because Theatre contains Room), but just an id. Otherwise you get in infinite loop of Theatre printing Room printing Theatre printing...